# How to remove padding when the size of the webpage decreases

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a footer element on my webpage, which is stuck to the bottom of the page. It has a margin-left of 225px (which is the size of the sidebar) but I would like to remove this margin so it spans across the entire page, whenever the size of the window decreases. I'm using a template so that when the window size decreases, the sidebar collapses. I manually added a margin-left to take into account the sidebar width.

This is how it looks like when there is a larger window: [image: Footer display on larger size]

This is how it looks when you minimize the window, when the sidebar disappears:
[image: Footer display on smaller size]

My html code uses the bootstrap jquery, css, as well as other template css and jquery files. My html code looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<!--contains all the content, the navbar at the top, and the sidebar -->
</div>
<footer class="footer" style="margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:225px;">
      <div class="container-fluid well" style="margin-bottom:0px">
        <nav class="pull-left">

          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="www.mcmaster.ca">Home</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Testing Purposes</a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="http://www.google.ca">Web Support</a></li>
          </ul>

        </nav>
        <p class="pull-right">
          &copy; 2017 <a href="www.mcmaster.ca">Sample Copyright</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Use media queries

Comment: Try to use stylesheet and no inline css, so after you can use easily media queries. @AndyHolmes +1

Comment: And to expand on both of them, here's some documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Would something like this work?
<footer class="footer" id="footer-collapse" style="@media (min-width: 600px) {
  margin-left:225px;
}">

Comment: Use a stylesheet

Comment: `<style>@media (min-width: 600px) { #footer-collapse { margin-left:225px; }
 }</style>` or put it in an external stylesheet

Comment: Thanks guys! It worked when I put it in my head section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries are your friend. As I understand it you are currently trying to adapt the desktop css for the mobile version. This would result in this query.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .footer {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

However the mobile first approach would be to start with the smaller screen and only add the margin for large screens.

```
.footer {
    margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .footer {
        margin-left: 225px;
    }
}
```